# Error: The OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable is missing or empty - Can't figure out why it's not recognized

Tags: typescript, next.js, openai-api, replit

I'm building in next.js on replit and attempting to implement an OpenAI integration, but I can't get it to recognize my OpenAI key. I have it correctly added as a secret (replaces .env.local if you're unfamiliar with replit) but I still keep getting this error.

I've tried several different ways to write openai.ts based on suggestions I could find:

sorry for the poor formatting this is my first time here :)

```
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env['OPENAI_API_KEY'], // This is the default and can be omitted
});

async function main() {
  const chatCompletion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    messages: [{ role: 'user', content: 'Say this is a test' }],
    model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
  });
}

main();
```

`results in:

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: The OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable is missing or empty; either provide it, or instantiate the OpenAI client with an apiKey option, like new OpenAI({ apiKey: 'My API Key' }).

Source
utils/openai.ts (3:15) @ eval

1 | import OpenAI from 'openai';
2 |

> 3 | const openai = new OpenAI({
> |             ^
> 4 | apiKey: process.env['OPENAI_API_KEY'], // This is the default and can be omitted
> 5 | });
> 6 |`

```
import { OpenAIApi, Configuration } from "openai";

const openAI = new OpenAIApi(new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
}));

async function createChatCompletion(prompt) {
  const response = await openAI.createChatCompletion({
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages: [
      {
        role: "user",
        content: prompt,
      },
    ],
  });
  return response;
}

export { openAI, createChatCompletion };
```

results in:
`
1 of 1 unhandled error
Server Error
TypeError: openai__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Configuration is not a constructor

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
utils/openai.ts (3:29) @ eval

1 | import { OpenAIApi, Configuration } from "openai";
2 |

> 3 | const openAI = new OpenAIApi(new Configuration({
> |                           ^
> 4 | apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
> 5 | }));
> 6 |`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. So, you're trying to set your API key in the `.env` file or using [Windows UI](https://www.thesagenext.com/support/set-environment-variables-in-windows)?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled on a similar problem and I've managed to reach OpenAI API.

1. I don't know if it's of any relations, but I've changed in .env.local the alias to NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_KEY because I work with vercel.
2. Because Next.js is on strictmode you're required to add the following to the OpenAI constructor dangerouslyAllowBrowser: true.

My code looks like this:

```
import OpenAI from "openai";

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_KEY
  , dangerouslyAllowBrowser: true
});

async function openaiReq() {
  const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    messages: [{ role: "system", content: "You are a helpful assistant." }],
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  });

  console.log(completion.choices[0]);
}

export default openaiReq();
```

I assume getting the 429 code "exceeded use limit" indicates that I've managed to reach the API.

[image: 429 code image]

hope this helps :)